# disproportionate differences in alpha/size in ggplot2 when set from dataframe column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this scatter plot:

```
iris$size <- 2
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, color=Species, size=size))
```

it works fine. Now I want to make just one of the points **slightly** bigger than the others, so I do:

```
iris$size[3] <- 2.5
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, color=Species, size=size))
```

This creates a disproportionate difference in size! The point `iris$size[3]` is not 20% bigger than the remaining points, it's *way bigger* (probably 10x). If I simply set `size=` to some constant, like 2.5, outside the `aes()` then the size 2.5 looks bigger in the way expected compared to 2.0, but not when it's set within the `aes()` as a column in the data frame.

The same is true for `alpha=`. If I set `alpha=` as a constant, not within `aes()` it works fine, but if I set some points to have an alpha of `0.6` and a few to have an alpha of `0.65`, the difference gets amplified to be tremendously big.

How can I get around this? How can I get alpha/size values to be interpreted from a column within `aes()` just as they do outside of it when calling `geom_point()`? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set size your values gets distributed between preset range - for the `scale_size_continuous()` default range is from 1 to 6. So the smallest value in your data gets `size=1` and largest values gets `size=6`. Using `scale_size_continuous()` and argument `range=` you can get own range, for example, the same as in your original data.

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, 
                color=Species, size=size))+
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,2.5),breaks=c(2,2.5))
```

If the data used for `size=` are actual size values you want to see on plot you can use  use `scale_size_identity()` which will interpret values specified for `size=` in `aes()` directly.

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, color=Species, size=size))+
  scale_size_identity()
```

Comment: Any idea why this happens? I see that with the OP's code, the size gets set to 6 and all others to 1.

Comment: @DidzisElferts: and same for alpha right? I use rpy2 so I coded this as: `ggplot2.scale_size(range=np.array([1,1.5]))`

Comment: @user248237dfsf Yes the same for alpha, there range is set to 0.1 and 1

Comment: @DidzisElferts: how do you know what the right range should be?

Comment: @DidzisElferts, so basically, it's implicitly taken as factors? (2 and 2.5 -> 1 and 6) or something like `seq(1, 6, length.out = 2)`

Comment: @Arun user248237dfsf rephrased my answer to better explain. The same holds for alpha

Comment: But you probably want `scale_size_area` to scale the area, rather than the radius.